# Disconnect from network using CLI

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, command-line, airport

I have an application where I am building a macOS native Wi-Fi wrapper using bash commands, when I reached the point to do the disconnection from a Wi-Fi network I found the following command which allows me to disconnect from a network:

```
$ sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport en0 -z
```

The only problem is that it asks me for my password when I use it, so I cannot include this inside my application.

I have been looking at the `networksetup` command, as this is the command allowing me to perform a Wi-Fi connection in the selected interface, but I cannot find any command to do the disconnection other than just turning OFF the Wi-Fi using the command:

```
$ networksetup -setairportpower Wi-Fi off
```

Is there any option to disconnect from the connected SSID without having to provide the system's password or turning OFF the Wi-Fi?

Comment: You could add a rule to `/etc/sudoers` (or in `/etc/sudoers.d/`)  to allow password-less use of `airport`

Comment: Is this an application or a bash script?

Comment: @nohillside This has to be done within an application which will be executed in other computers as well, unless I can execute a command to add that rule (without requiring user password) that won't work.

Comment: @mmmmmm It is a Qt application which calls a process that runs the command in a bash shell.

Comment: Then in Qt there will be a call to call macOS authentication dialog to get the username and password. Playing with network settings requires admin rights

Comment: You could add this rule during the installation/deployment process.